# How can i fix 'Manager isn't accessible via Weekstaat instances'?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change status to 'ingedient'.
When I click the 'indienen' button this error appears: 
Manager isn't accessible via Weekstaat instances.
How can I fix this error?------------

this is my index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'weekstaat-indienen' Weekstaat.id  %}" method=POST>
                       {% csrf_token %}
                      <button id="approve-btn" type="submit">Approve</button>
                     </form>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center">
                      <button type="button" class="read-Contract btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'read_Weekstaat' Weekstaat.id %}">
                        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" class="update-Contract btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'update_Weekstaat' Weekstaat.id %}">
                        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
                      </button>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            {% else %}
              <p class="text-primary">U heeft nog geen Weekstaat</p>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function bevestigIndienen(){
        if(confirm('U staat op het punt een weekstaat in te dienen. Weet u het zeker?') != true){
            document.getElementById('formulierIndienen').action = '';
            window.location.href = "{% url 'home' %}";
        }
    }
```

this is my view.py

```
def indienen(request, id):
    global Weekstaat
    Weekstaat = Weekstaat.objects.get(pk=id)
    Weekstaat.Status = 'Ingedient'
    Weekstaat.save()
    return redirect('../../weekstaat')
```

this is my model.py

```
class Weekstaat(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Niet ingediend',)
    jaar = models.ForeignKey(Jaar, default=datetime.now().year, null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    week = models.ForeignKey(Week, default=date.today().isocalendar()[1], null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    werknemer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='weekstaat_werknemer', null=False, blank=False, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    maandag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    dinsdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    woensdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    donderdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    vrijdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    zaterdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    zondag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.jaar) + ' week ' + str(self.week) + str(self.werknemer) + str(self.status)
```

this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
            path('', views.Index.as_view(), name='indexs'),
            path('create/', views.WeekstaatCreateView.as_view(), name='create_Weekstaat'),
            path('update/<int:pk>', views.WeekstaatUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_Weekstaat'),
            path('read/<int:pk>', views.WeekstaatReadView.as_view(), name='read_Weekstaat'),
            path('delete/<int:pk>', views.WeekstaatDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_Weekstaat'),
            path('indienen/<int:id>', views.indienen, name='weekstaat-indienen'),
        ]
```

Comment: can you show **STATUS_CHOICES**

Comment: yes: STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Niet ingediend','Niet ingediend'),
    ('Ingedient', 'Ingedient'),
    ('Afgekeurd','Afgekeurd'),
    ('In afwachting','In afwachting'),

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by a typo here `Weekstaat.Status = 'Ingedient'` it should be `Weekstaat.status = 'Ingedient'`. NB: lowercase

Answer (score 1):

In your function `indienen` you override the global variable `Weekstaat` with a `Weekstaat` instance:

```
def indienen(request, id):
    global Weekstaat
    Weekstaat = Weekstaat.objects.get(pk=id)
    ...
```

The second time this method runs you are trying to get the Manager via the instance. This is not possible hence the error message. Try using another variable name instead:

```
def indienen(request, id):
    global Weekstaat
    weekstaat = Weekstaat.objects.get(pk=id)  # notice  lowercase w
    weekstaat.Status = 'Ingedient'
    weekstaat.save()
    return redirect('../../weekstaat')
```

Comment: There's no need to have global here at all.

Comment: The error message is gone but it still doesn't update status

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems not appropriate. Change your view as below,

```
def indienen(request, id):
    weekstaat_instance = Weekstaat.objects.get(pk=id)
    weekstaat_instance.Status = 'Ingedient'
    weekstaat_instance.save()
    return redirect('../../weekstaat')
```